# Convert short year format to full - jquery input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I have Jquery input mask date that has format `mm/dd/yyyy`. When I type `17` for a year I want to convert it to `2017` and that works good but I have the issue when I type `21` it converts to `201` not `2021`.

You can here see example:
https://jsfiddle.net/u3em5bmr/1/

Comment: It would be better if you post the code here.

Comment: @Edin Puzic Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Sandy2016, yes check here https://jsfiddle.net/806ju2aL/8/

Answer (score -1):

```js
str = 'xx 22.07.03 yy';
str = str.replace(/(\d{2}.\d{2}).(\d{2})/g,'$1.20$2'); // $1='22.07' $2='03'
alert(str);
```